# Why am I seeing system-wide graphical glitches on a new windows PC?

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

I recently bought a new PC, and I keep seeing strange blocks or extra pixels rendered around certain icons, system-wide.  I am using intel UHD graphics 750.  This still occurs after updating to the latest intel generic graphics drivers and doing several Windows updates.  These glitches are captured by screenshots.

[image: Examples of glitched images]

I'm awaiting a manufacturer response, but in the meantime I've updated my BIOS drivers and ran the diagnostics provided by the manufacturer.  By all measures, the system seems to be fine, and test sequences run correctly.  But the glitches still happen.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your new hardware?  Just as you suspect?  Yeah.. not cool buddy.

Comment: Update the drivers and software. If that doesn't fix things, return it or warranty service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this does not get to the root of the problem, but "System wide" turned out to only be a handful of apps which use GPU hardware acceleration by default.  Disabling hardware acceleration in these apps seems to eliminate the glitches.